# viewpager IllegalStateException with dynamic data

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm creating tablayout tabs dynamically from webservice. The tablayout is attached to a viewpager. When I swipe the pages in viewpager, the app crashes with a IllegalStateException. I searched for this exception and found that it might be due to fragment and so I used `getChildFragmentManager` as suggested in some SO posts. I also used `v` instead of FragmentPagerAdapter but still I get the same error. Is there something I'm doing wrong as I used the same code in activity and its working fine.

```css
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.nits_35.wrd, PID: 5175
                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 4, found: 15 Pager id: com.nits_35.wrd:id/category_viewpager Pager class: class cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.nits_35.wrd.views.fragments.Frag_Seller_Market$SampleFragmentPagerAdapter
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1167)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16924)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1189)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1189)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2722)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5602)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2549)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2252)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1323)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6706)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invok
```

```html
public class Frag_Seller_Market extends Fragment {

    
    private AutoScrollViewPager category_viewpager;
    
    private SampleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter;

  

    public Frag_Seller_Market() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    private TabLayout seller_tabs_store;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.seller_fragment_market, container, false);
        seller_tabs_store=(TabLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.seller_tabs_store);
      
    
        category_viewpager=(AutoScrollViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.category_viewpager);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       

        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()){

             fetchCategoryList();
        }else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

   
    private void fetchCategoryList(){
        if(arrayList!=null)arrayList.clear();
        pd.setMessage("loading...");
        pd.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Utility.CATEGORYLIST,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        System.out.println("Category_List_Response"+response);


                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jObj.getInt("Ack")==1){
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("CategoryList");
                                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject main = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Model market = new Model();
                                    market.setProduct_category_id(main.getString("id"));
                                    market.setProduct_category_name(main.getString("name"));
                                  

                                    arrayList.add(market);

                                }

                                if(getActivity()!=null)
                                category_viewpager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity(), arrayList));
                                seller_tabs_store.setupWithViewPager(category_viewpager);

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            System.out.println("jay_JSONError "+e);
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.tooslow),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.nointernet),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    System.out.println("jay_AuthFailureError "+error);
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_ServerError "+error);
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_NetworkError "+error);
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_ParseError "+error);
                }
            }
        }) ;

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }

    public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Model> arrayList;

        public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, ArrayList<Model> arrayList) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
            this.arrayList=arrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           return Frag_store_productwiselist.newInstance(arrayList.get(position).getProduct_category_id());

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return arrayList.get(position).getProduct_category_name();
        }
    }

  
}
```

Comment: call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after setadapter

Comment: Can I set adapter in `onViewCreated()` and use `notifyDataSetChanged()` in Volley service?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a new adapter every time, you can just notify it to update views according if any data changes.

So what you can do is that:

```
if(sampleFragmentPagerAdapter == null){
sampleFragmentPagerAdapter = new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity(), arrayList);
}else{
sampleFragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
category_viewpager.setAdapter(sampleFragmentPagerAdapter);                                
seller_tabs_store.setupWithViewPager(category_viewpager);
```

And make the sampleFragmentPagerAdapter, a global object in your activity or fragment.

Comment: Tried it but still getting same exception @Sac

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message:

> The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 4, found: 15

The problem come from `getCount` function in your `PagerAdapter`:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
```

From this function, everytime you `add/remove/clear` your `arrayList`, you need to call `viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

P/s: you need to override `getItemPosition` function of `Adapter` to make it works.:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    // Causes adapter to reload all Fragments when
    // notifyDataSetChanged is called
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Comment: I added getItemPosition in pageradapter but still getting the same error @Kingfisher

Comment: you need to call `viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` everytime you change the size of your `arrayList` as well.

Comment: the arraylist is only changing when I hit the API to get the data for Tabs. that's where arraylist is changing. So, do I've to add notifyDataSetChanged() inside for loop?

Comment: you should call it after the `for loop` and remember to call it when you clear your arrayList.

Comment: if I add notifyDataSetChanged() after the line ` if(arrayList!=null)arrayList.clear();`, the app crashes automatically with the same error without swiping pages.

Comment: how do you call it? is it same error? you should post your `autoscroll view pager` as well. maybe the problem come from it.